# What is the Swift compiler doing with my return type? Is it somehow casting?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, coercion, type-coercion

I have a method:

```
func allRegions() -> [MappedRegion] {
    return self.items.lazy.compactMap { item in item.valveAny }.flatMap { valve in valve.regions }
}
```

I was frankly surprised this worked. I'm doing lazy stuff here, but it's apparently having a lazy sequence that turns into a sequence of MappedRegion be the same.

Then I was doing some poor mans timing and modified the function to read:

```
func allRegions() -> [MappedRegion] {
    let startTime = Date()
    let result = self.items.lazy.compactMap { item in item.valveAny }.flatMap { valve in valve.regions }
    self.sumRender += (Date() - startTime)
    return result
}
```

But that created an error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazySequence<[StatusRowItem]>.Elements, ValveAbstract?>>, ValveAbstract>.Elements, [MappedRegion]>>>' (aka 'LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<LazyMapSequence<Array<StatusRowItem>, Optional<ValveAbstract>>>, ValveAbstract>, Array<MappedRegion>>>>') to return type '[MappedRegion]'
```

That was initially a surprise. I found that if I specified the return type of `result` as `[MappedRegion]` all was happy (e.g. `let result:[MappedRegion] = ...`).

What is going on here? I get that the original one line function is inferring the result type as [MappedRegion], so I'm probably not getting much benefits from the lazy use. But what confuses me, is that this coercion from a lazy sequence to a fixed array automagically is reminiscent of casting in C, and I thought that Swift didn't do casting?

Comment: It might be the compiler optimizing out the `lazy` call as it detects it it won't be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no casting going on. There are simply two different `flatMap` functions being called. [`LazyMapSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazymapsequence) has two `flatMap(_:)` functions (well, technically four, but two are deprecated).

In your first code block, [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazymapsequence/2996181-flatmap) function is inferred (because this version of `flatMap` has a return type that matches your `allRegions` function's return type):

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element] where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

And in your second code block, [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazymapsequence/2996179-flatmap) function is inferred (because there is no type annotation on your local variable that's forcing it to choose the above version of `flatMap`):

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: @escaping (Element) -> SegmentOfResult) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazyMapSequence<Base, Element>, SegmentOfResult>>> where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```